Is my geometrical "proof" of CMVT correct?
In his A Course of Pure Mathematics, GH Hardy proves and gives a "geometrical demonstration" of the LMVT, which goes nearly like this:

THEOREM. If $\phi(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ then there is a value $x=\xi\in(a,b)$ such that $\phi(b)-\phi (a)=(b-a)\phi'(\xi)$.
 Proof
 Let there be a function:
$$f(x):= \phi(b)-\phi(x)-\frac{b-x}{b-a}\{\phi(b)-\phi(a)\}$$
Then, $f(a)=f(b)=0$. It follows from Rolle's theorem that there is a $x=\xi\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(\xi)=0$ &c.
 Geometrical demonstration
Fig.$41$
 If the curve $APB\text{ see fig.41 }$ has a tangent at all points of its length then there must be a point $P$ where the tangent is parallel to $AB$, for $\phi'(\xi)$ is the tangent of the angle which the tangent at $P$
makes with $OX$ and $\frac{\phi(b)-\phi(a)}{b-a}$ is the slope of chord $AB$. The function $f(x)$ is the locus of the difference between the ordinates of a point on the curve and the corresponding point on the chord.

Inspired by this, I tried to construct a rough "geometrical proof" of the CMVT (Cauchy's MVT).

I begin with the locus $L: KX - \kappa K'X'$ as $x$ is varied between $a$ and $b$, $\kappa = \frac{\tan \alpha}{\tan \beta}$. From $\Delta PKB$ and $\Delta P'K'B'$, $\kappa = \frac{PK}{P'K'}$. So, we can write $(PX-PK) - \kappa (P'X'-P'K')=PX-\kappa P'X'$. If $T$ be the tangent to $L$ at any point on it, the slope of $T$ is, therefore, $(\tan \alpha - f'(x))-\kappa(\tan \beta - g'(x)) = \kappa g'(x) - f'(x)$. I think this is how it should go like (but the diagram seems somewhat erroneous), but I am not sure if it counts as a real "proof" or what its missing to be a real proof. Any help is appreciated!
